# VB.NET : Generate all possible words on file

Tags: vb.net, combinations

Example :

If a got word "don" then file will contain

```
ddd
ddo
ddn
dod
doo
don
dnd
dno
dnn
odd
odo
odn
ood
<...>
```

I have no idea to do this. Not less then 3 symbol words.

Comment: Look here, there's a solution for you
[on StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853653/vb-net-all-combinations/7854261#7854261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presented a solution in Experts Exchange, which you may not be able to see (if you never payed them) so I copy it for you:

Question was:
I have n items and each item can be assigned a 1 or a 2. So I would like to get the matrix result that would generate all possible combinations.

For eg. if n= 3 , then the possible outcomes are : I  need an algorithm that can generate this series for n . Please help thanks. ideally i would like to store the result in a datatable

```
 1 1 1
 1 1 2
 1 2 1
 2 1 1
 2 1 2
 1 2 2
 2 2 1
 2 2 2
```

Answer:

```
    Dim HighestValue As Integer = 2 ' max value
    Dim NrOfValues As Integer = 3 ' nr of values in one result
    Dim Values(NrOfValues) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To NrOfValues - 1
        Values(i) = 1
    Next
    Values(NrOfValues - 1) = 0 ' to generate first as ALL 1
    For i = 1 To HighestValue ^ NrOfValues
        Values(NrOfValues - 1) += 1
        For j As Integer = NrOfValues - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Values(j) > HighestValue Then
                Values(j) = 1
                Values(j - 1) += 1
            End If
        Next
        Dim Result As String = ""
        For j As Integer = 0 To NrOfValues - 1
            Result = Result & CStr(Values(j))
        Next
        Debug.WriteLine(Result)
    Next
```

Ok Here's the solution, you just need to change the Debug.Writeline with a write to your file

```
    Dim HighestValue As Integer = 3 ' max value
    Dim NrOfValues As Integer = 3 ' nr of values in one result
    Dim Values(NrOfValues) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To NrOfValues - 1
        Values(i) = 1
    Next
    Values(NrOfValues - 1) = 0 ' to generate first as ALL 1
    For i = 1 To HighestValue ^ NrOfValues
        Values(NrOfValues - 1) += 1
        For j As Integer = NrOfValues - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Values(j) > HighestValue Then
                Values(j) = 1
                Values(j - 1) += 1
            End If
        Next
        Dim Result As String = ""
        For j As Integer = 0 To NrOfValues - 1
            If Values(j) = 1 Then Result = Result & "d"
            If Values(j) = 2 Then Result = Result & "o"
            If Values(j) = 3 Then Result = Result & "n"
            'Result = Result & CStr(Values(j))
        Next
        Debug.WriteLine(Result)
    Next
```

Comment: How to use this function? I need return a string.

Comment: Take the string in Debug.WriteLine(Result), which contains the values of e solution, concatenate them to ger all together, I can only give you the algorithm, you'll have to adapt it to your needs